# Centos 6 VPS - Fresh Install - No Network

Tags: centos, networking, vps

First: Thank you for reading and trying to help.

I just installed Centos 6 (6.3) on a Microsoft HyperV VPS (Server 2012), from the minimal ISO. After install, only the loopback interface shows.

```
ifconfig -a
lo    Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

... and that's it. I've searched and read several posts around the Internet, most of which were solved by deleting `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`, but that file does not exist on my system. Their issue is typically due to cloning the server and the MAC address is stored in the rules, doesn't match, and fails to initialize.

`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` also did not exist. I created it with very standard default values:

```
DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
PERSISTENT_DHCLIENT=1
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE=Ethernet
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
IPV6_DEFROUTE=no
IPV6_PEERDNS=no
IPV6_PEERROUTES=no
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME="eth0"
```

Still, no network. `ifup eth0` produces:

```
Device eth0 does not seem to be present, delaying initialization.
```

Running `dhclient` returns with no output. This step is what got things working for Centos 7.

`lspci` is not part of 'minimal', so not available, not that I'm sure it would help in a Virtual machine.

Any help, tips, tricks, would be appreciated.

Background: I am not very familiar with Centos, I have been using mostly Debian-based flavors for many years. I've been using some form of Linux as my primary desktop operating system since 2003, so I am not afraid of building files wherever they need to be, or hunting for things, or gathering data. I was able to get a Centos 7 VPS guest running on the same VPS Host server. The goal of THIS install is to get a legacy web application running that is not compatible with the newer PHP in Centos 7, and our web host uses Centos (and last night updated from 6 to 7, breaking the application).

Comment: After 10 hours of tinkering, I could find no solution. I ended up getting Centos 6.9 running in VirtualBox, having had no luck with Microsoft HyperV. VirtualBox has MUCH more flexible and specific network emulation options (but only produced kernel panics with Centos 6.3). I am not going to pursue an answer to the original question, but I will happily test one if someone sends it in.

Comment: Sometimes you have add a virtual lan to the virtual machine via hyper-v manager. I didn't use the hyper-V but i have used ovirt. You can use 
ip a command to view the connected network devices.